# How to set default printer programmatically

Tags: language-agnostic, printers

I want to set a default printer to print the badges for events . I don't know how to set it. As all the users using this application should have a specific printer attached to their PC. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, JS does not have any access to hardware, unless you are on some sort of elevated platform, like a plugin perhaps.

Comment: Actually the question is not particularly regarding javascript.It may be any coding language.Is there any chance to set the printer settings by default

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Actually am on cloud based platform. Is there any chance to set the printer by default based on javascript, jquery, Html?

Answer (score 4):

The furtherest you can go is show the print dialog with JavaScript. You can't set default printers.